# I can't install atom using apt-get commands

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, kde, atom

I am new in Linux and debian 10 (KDE) is the first distribution that I am using.

But when I'm trying to install atom editor when I use this command It gives me an error :

```
command >> sudo apt-get install atom
```

Output :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package atom
```

I looked it up in google but i couldn't find anything to fix my problem.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: You can download a .deb package and install it:

`$ wget https://atom.io/download/deb -O atom.deb`
`$ sudo dpkg -i atom.deb`

More info here: https://tecadmin.net/install-atom-editor-on-ubuntu-debian-and-linuxmint/

Comment: yes I did sudo apt-get update

Comment: I tried with dpkg but it says that the dependencies are not installed

Comment: Have a look at what's missing at your computer and try to install it using apt. Some guidance for you is here: https://github.com/atom/atom#linux You're likely missing some of these `sudo apt install git gconf2 gconf-service libgtk2.0-0 libudev1 libgcrypt20 libnotify4 libxtst6 libnss3 python gvfs-bin xdg-utils libcap2`

Comment: Following  [this guide](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#debian-and-ubuntu-debapt) I could install it in Debian 9.

Comment: Looks like the packaging for debian is a bit stalled. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=747824

Comment: This command "should work", but it does't work on Ubuntu 18.04.  curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/AtomEditor/atom/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
sudo snap install atom --classic
```

Comment: On Debian you first might have to install the snap daemon with `sudo apt install snapd`.

Answer (score 1):

To install `atom` through `apt`, you need to add the atom repository :

```
wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```

Atom manual : [Debian and Ubuntu (deb/apt)](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#debian-and-ubuntu-debapt)

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, this produces the error E: Unable to locate package atom